# Rails Ajax Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I've been looking for a ajax search gem for Rails but haven't had any luck.

Has anybody done simple ajax search in Rails and or used a gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need gem for this, but here is good place to search gems: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/
Try to implement ajax search by yourself. It's easy in Rails =)

Comment: I tried to include search using this RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form but I had problems

Comment: The search form doesn't appear

Comment: This railscast episode is outdated, try this instead: http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

Comment: Ok. The search form appears now but when I type something in and hit search, I get a ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Documents#index error

Comment: I guess you have to show some of your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21193/discussion-between-user1658756-and-anatolk)